# Turn RGB blinker via serial

Tags: serial, programming, serial-data

I have a BLUno bluetooth arduino based on uno.

the logic kind of works, I am connecting ok to the phone, getting and sending messages via blue tooth

but with the serial data, Im having problems using it, and with the logic.

I want to have the option to turn ON/OFF some RGB LEDs, the problem is that the state is sometimes erratic.

here the code

```
int redLED = 2;
int greenLED = 4;
int blueLED = 3;

static bool redRunning;
static bool greenRunning;
static bool blueRunning;
static bool freq = 34;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);               //initial the Serial
  Serial.write("started");

  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueLED, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(blueLED, HIGH);

  redRunning = false;
  greenRunning = false;
  blueRunning = false;
  freq = false;
}


void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  f{
String s = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

//    String s = Serial.readStringUntil("#");   // Until CR (Carriage Return)
//    s.replace("#", "");
    Serial.println("s:" + s);


if (s == "red_ON")
{
  redRunning = true;
}

if (s == "red_OFF")
{
  redRunning = false;

}  if (s == "green_ON")
{
  greenRunning = true;

}  if (s == "green_OFF")
{
  greenRunning = false;

}  if (s == "blue_ON")
{
  blueRunning = true;

}  if (s == "blue_OFF")
{
  blueRunning = false;

}

 }

 //



  if (redRunning) {
//    Serial.println("redRunning");

digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
delay(125);
digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
delay(125);
  }

  if (greenRunning) {
//    Serial.println("greenRunning");

digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
delay(125);
digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
delay(125);
  }

  if (blueRunning) {
    //    Serial.println("blueRunning");

    digitalWrite(blueLED, LOW);
    delay(125);
      digitalWrite(blueLED, HIGH);
    delay(125);
  }


  if (!redRunning && !greenRunning && !blueRunning) {
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(blueLED, HIGH);
  }

   }
```

So what is the proper way to handle state? so the LED stay blinking? but also can turn off all LEDs
also if I can turn LEDs combined, at the moment, I'm turning on one, then the other,

All these problems come from not understanding how to handle state internally, and manage changes that come via serial.

Comment: use `blueRunning = HIGH;`  to store the LED state directly .... then set all three colors at the same time withhout using an `if` statement ... `digitalWrite(blueLED, blueRunning);` `delay(125);` `digitalWrite(blueLED, LOW);`

Comment: @jsotola what a great way to do it! thanks! please make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are handling the state quite well, but if you spend some time to some other topics, I'm sure you get it working:

1. Instead of `delay`'s everywhere, use just one at the end, and make sure you handle all state before that delay. This means that you set all your states the way you want, that single `delay` gives a much easier sketch to analyze.
2. Split your sketch in separate parts (within the `loop` function):

   - Read serial input
   - Adjust states according to your serial input
   - Adjust states according to time (for blinking purposes)
   - Set the GPIO pins for the LEDs based on that state
   - Delay
     Regarding the states, you use now 3 'running' states, one for each color, this is good. Probably it's easier to keep these variables attached to the serial input (so if you get "green_ON", greenRunning is always `true`, else `false`. So you don't need to always set them to `false` in the beginning of the `loop` function, just once during declaration or within `setup`.

Than you make another (global) variable that defines if (any) LED is in HIGH state (if it WOULD be running) of LOW. This variable you change every 125 ms (or whatever speed you like). You can flip this variable every 125 ms (`ledsOn = !ledsOn`).

So you get something like (# = pseudo code), for red only, rest is similar:

in global:

```
bool redRunning = false;
bool ledsOn = false;
```

in `loop`:

```
// Read serial input
# Read input

// Set states
# if serial data Red On is received
   redRunning = true;
# if serial data Red Off is received
   redRunning = false;

ledsOn = !ledsOn; 

// Set LEDs
digitalWrite(redLED, redRunning && ledsOn ? HIGH : LOW);

// Delay
delay(125);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some untested code that uses a non-blocking timer to flash the leds.

```
uint8_t redLED   = 2;
uint8_t greenLED = 4;
uint8_t blueLED  = 3;

static uint8_t redRunning   = HIGH;   // leds off at start
static uint8_t greenRunning = HIGH;
static uint8_t blueRunning  = HIGH;

// static bool freq = 34;             // not sure what this is


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);               // initialize the Serial
  Serial.write("started");

  pinMode(redLED,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueLED,  OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(redLED,   HIGH);       // leds off
  digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(blueLED,  HIGH);

//freq     = false;
  tick     = false;                   // time interval signal
  ledState = false;                   // state of led display

  static uint32_t ledTicker = millis();
}

void loop() {

  if (millis() - ledTicker >= 125) {             // Once every 125 ms
    ledTicker = millis();
    tick = true;                                 // set the tick flag
    ledState = !ledState;                        // changes state at every tick 
  }

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String s = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

//  String s = Serial.readStringUntil("#");      // Until CR (Carriage Return)
//  s.replace("#", "");
    Serial.println("s:" + s);


    if (s == "red_ON"   )  redRunning   = LOW ;  // sometimes, this format is easier to read
    if (s == "red_OFF"  )  redRunning   = HIGH;

    if (s == "green_ON" )  greenRunning = LOW ; 
    if (s == "green_OFF")  greenRunning = HIGH;

    if (s == "blue_ON"  )  blueRunning  = LOW ;
    if (s == "blue_OFF" )  blueRunning  = HIGH;
  }

  //
  if (tick) {                                    // 125 ms passed, so update the leds
    tick = false;                                // reset tick so that leds change only once every tick

    if (ledState) {                              // state of leds at this tick
      digitalWrite(redLED  , redRunning  );
      digitalWrite(greenLED, greenRunning);
      digitalWrite(blueLED , blueRunning );
    }  
    else {                                       // all off this time around
      digitalWrite(redLED  , HIGH);
      digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(blueLED , HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```